# How to use GNU GRUB 2.04 to boot UBUNTU

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I clean installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS-Desktop-AMD64 from a DVD written with an ISO image file.

The installation went through its steps, including erasing all partitions and formatting the 1 TB Solid-State drive (SSD) as a single partition.

I then removed the DVD from its drive and rebooted the box. Rather than booting Ubuntu, a single line error message splashed for a fraction of a second (couldn't read it) and GNU GRUB 2.04 was displayed, waiting for a command.

Entering "boot" as a command resulted in an error message saying I have to load a kernel first. Unfortunately the GRUB documentation is of no use to solve the problem.

Why didn't the box booted Ubuntu? How to use GRUB to load a kernel? what files should I specify?

Comment: You install is not working. Re download the iso and verify it. Make a new live media and re install the OS on the computer. A working new system does not show grub on a single OS system unless there is a problem,

Comment: At the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2465764) we are developing and testing the tool `system-info` to identify hardware and configurations in order to make it easier to help people with Ubuntu. Please download and run it. Let it upload the a report file to a pastebin and post a link to it in the original question. It will make it easier tor me and other people to know where to start looking for a solution to your problem. (I would recommend the DEV/TEST version.)

Comment: ... Run the `system-info` script **from the live drive**, that you used to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Dear @sudodus, 
My box is stuck with GNU GRUB. No linux and no browser. How am I to download, install, run and upload anything ...?

Comment: I think you have the installer drive (I would guess an USB drive). You can run a live system 'Try Ubuntu'.

Comment: Dear @sudodus, thanks! I'll try that, although my level of knowledge about fetching the source from GitHub, and doing the whole chain of tools down to an executable application, might not be enough to do all that.